# Is there a way to scp a file onto my local machine while logged into a server via ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh, server, scp

The title says most of it, but I'll be more specific:

When I want to `scp` a file from my local machine to a server I would use:

```
local_user@my_hostname:~$ scp local_file.txt remote_user@some_server:~/
remote_user@some_servers password:
local_file.txt                100%     0     0.0KB/s     00:00
local_user@my_hostname:~$
```

As you can see, I am prompted for a password for that ssh server, and the file would be securely copied.

---

Thus far, If I want a file copied to my local machine from a remote ssh server, I've been using scp like this:

```
local_user@my_hostname:~$ scp remote_user@some_server:~/server_file.txt ~/
remote_user@some_servers password:
server_file.txt               100%     0     0.0KB/s     00:00
local_user@my_hostname:~$
```

As you can see, I am asked again for the password. It would be nice to skip the password if I am already logged into the server via ssh with something along the lines of this:

```
local_user@my_hostname:~$ ssh remote_user@some_server
remote_user@some_servers password:
server login success!
remote_user@some_server:~$ scp server_file.txt local_user@my_hostname:~/
remote_user@some_sercer:~$
```

Is this possible? Or practical?

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible directly using `ssh` and `scp`. you can however use additional utilities. A very flexible one is `netcat`. Take a look at this tutorial: https://nakkaya.com/2009/04/15/using-netcat-for-file-transfers/

Comment: Or maybe with rsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `ssh` into the remote host, set up a reverse tunnel.

```
ssh -R 12345:localhost:22 remote_user@some_server
```

Port 12345 on the remote host is now connected to port 22 on your host, meaning connections to 12345 are tunneled back over the existing `ssh` connection to your local machine's `sshd` service.

On the remote machine, run

```
scp -P 12345 server_file.txt localhost:~/
```

to copy the file back to your home directory.

If you don't want to remember to use `-R`, you can add the following to your local `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
    RemoteForward 12345:localhost:22
```

and the tunnel will be set up for any connection automatically.

You can also specify a port of 0  (`0:localhost:22`) to let `ssh` choose an available port for you; the chosen port is written to standard output once the connection is established.

Comment: remote_user@some_server:~$ scp -P 12345 test.txt localhost:~/
connect_to localhost port 22: failed.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
lost connection

Comment: Make sure you are actually running `sshd` on port 22.